# Graph Theory Paths

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every graph $G$ with $|G| < \|G\|$ contains a P$_{4}$. (P$_{4}$ is path with length $3$, $|G|$ is the number of vertices and $\|G\|$ is the number of edges).

Would induction be the only way prove this? Started of with base case $|G|$ greater than or equal to $4$. Then tried induction after that, but got a little lost.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you clarify what $|G|$ and $\|G\|$ each represent?  The number of vertices and the number of edges?

Comment: Yes you are correct I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably doable by induction, but here's an alternative for the fun of it.

Suppose $G$ has no $P_4$.  We show that $G$ has $|E(G)| \leq |V(G)|$, which proves that statement by contraposition.

For some vertex $v$, denote by $N(v)$ its set of neighbors.

If $v$ has at least 3 neighbors, then all $x \in N(v)$ are of degree one.
Otherwise, take $x,y,z \in N(v)$, and suppose $x$ has a neighbor $x'$.  Then, at least one of $zvxx'$ or $yvxx'$ forms a $P_4$. 
So, $v$ and $N(v)$ form a connected component of $G$ with less edges than vertices.

If $v$ has exactly two neighbors $x, y$, then the only possible other neighbor of $x$ is $y$, and vice-versa.
So, $v,x,y$ form a connected component with 3 vertices and at most 3 edges.

If $v$ has one neighbor $v'$, it is either in one of the connected components described above (if $v'$ has degree at least 2), or in a connected component that contains only $v$ and $v'$.

In the end, every connected component has at least as many vertices than edges.  So we must deduce that $|E(G)| \leq |V(G)|$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you this is so much better than the induction I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

> Prove that every graph $G$ with $|G| < ||G||$ contains a $P_4$  . ($P_4$   is path with length $3$, |G| is the number of vertices and $||G||$ is the number of edges).
>
> Would induction be the only way prove this? Started of with base case $|G|$ greater than or equal to $4$. Then tried induction after that, but got a little lost.

So basically prove a graph G with more edges than vertices has a path of length 4 somewhere. We show this below.

Assume your graph has 1 vertex and 2 edges. Impossible.
2 vertices, 3 edges...impossible
3 vertices, 4 edges...impossible
4 vertices, 5 edges = possible!!

So our base case $n = 4$ is true. We assume all graphs $G$ with $4 \leq n$ vertices and at least $n-1$ edges has a path of length 4.

Assume this is true for all integers from $4$ to $n$. Then we prove that a graph $G$ with $n+1$ vertices contains a $P_4$.

Well a graph with $n+1$ vertices might as well be our original graph with $n$ vertices and 1 more vertex with a number $n_0$ of edges connected to it, where $0 \leq n_0 \leq n$. If we remove this vertex with $n_0$ edges, this leaves a graph with a $P_4$.

Comment: And what if the graph with $n + 1$ vertices is not the original graph with 1 extra disconnected graph ?  Meaning, take some vertex $v$.  It's entirely possible that $G - v$ has less than $n$ edges (in which case you can't apply induction), but $G$ has more than $n + 1$ edges.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The graph with $n$ vertices has $n+1$ edges, by assumption. We have to prove that the graph with $n+1$ vertices and at least $n+2$ edges has a $P_4$. Anyway, I've edited my answer.

Comment: You need to show that if $G$ has $n + 1$ vertices and at least $n + 2$ edges, then it has a $P_4$.  Your proof holds in the special case that $G$ has a disconnected vertex.  Or at least, it shows that it works when $G$ has a vertex $v$ that, upon removal, leaves a graph with $n$ vertices and at least $n + 1$ edges.  This is not an assumption !  It needs to be shown that this can be done, i.e. that $v$ exists.  The assumption is that $G$ has $n + 1$ vertices, $n + 2$ edges - nothing else.

Comment: @ManuelLafond I see your downvote and raise you an edit.

Comment: Meh, that was a bit harsh :)  Downvote removed, but hopefully you see what I'm talking about.